# Kotlin: filterNotNull for values in a Map<K,V?>

Tags: kotlin, idioms

Here's the Kotlin code I'd like to write (with extra type annotations for clarity):

```
fun test(alpha: String, beta: String, gamma: String? = null, delta: String? = null) {
    val r1: Map<String, String?> =
        hashMapOf(
            "alpha" to alpha,
            "beta" to beta,
            "gamma" to gamma,
            "delta" to delta
        )
    val r2: Map<String, String> = r1.filterValues { it != null }
    callSomeFunction(r2)  // expects a parameter of type Map<String, String>
}
```

Unfortunately, `r1.filterValues { it != null }` gives me back a `Map<String, String?>`, not a `Map<String, String>`.  I understand why this is; it's the same reason that `listOf(1, null).filter { it != null }` has a different type from `listOf(1, null).filterNotNull()`.  However, I still need to solve my problem!

Is there an idiomatic way to "filterValuesNotNull" from a `Map`?

Or, stepping up a level, is there some other idiomatic way to say "give me a `Map` of the following arguments, but skip those whose values are null"? I could resort to [this](https://pl.kotl.in/DSomTAZSR), but I don't want to:

```
fun test(alpha: String, beta: String, gamma: String? = null, delta: String? = null) {
    var r1: MutableMap<String, String> = mutableMapOf(
        "alpha" to alpha,
        "beta" to beta
    )
    if (gamma != null) {
        r1["gamma"] = gamma
    }
    if (delta != null) {
        r1["delta"] = delta
    }
    callSomeFunction(r1)  // expects a parameter of type Map<String, String>
}
```

Comment: IMO, there should be a `filterNotNullKeys()` function and *that* would be the idiomatic way. They opened an issue for it on themselves and then haven't touched it in six years. Weird. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-4734

Answer (score 2):

Here's 2 ways to do it, although whether either is idiomatic, I do not know.

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST)
fun filterNotNullUnchecked(map: Map<String, String?>): Map<String, String> =
  map.filterValues { it != null } as Map<String, String>
```

EDIT: As @Tenfour04 pointed out, this isn't unsafe, just unchecked because of type erasure, and adding a `Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST)` annotation makes the warning go away.

```
fun filterNotNullUgly(map: Map<String, String?>): Map<String, String> {
  val map2 = HashMap<String, String>()
  for ((k, v) in map) if (v != null) map2[k] = v
  return map2
}
```

Comment: The first way isn't unsafe, just unchecked by the compiler. Slap a `@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")` on there an you're good.

Answer (score 2):

The functions that in my opinion should be in the stdlib:

```
fun <K,V: Any> Map<K,V?>.filterNotNullValuesTo(destination: MutableMap<K,V>): Map<K, V> {
    for ((key, value) in entries) if (value != null) destination[key] = value
    return destination
}

fun <K,V: Any> Map<K,V?>.filterNotNullValues(): Map<K,V> = filterNotNullValuesTo(mutableMapOf())
```

Answer (score 1):

hm, I suppose, it can be decided on that way

```
val newMap: Map<String, String> = r1.mapNotNull { (key, value) ->
    value?.let { key to it }
}.toMap()
```